# How to read an environment variable in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

On my Android's `build.gradle`, there's

```
ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
```

I'd like to replace it with an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

```
ndkVersion System.getenv("ANDROID_NDK_VERSION")
```